# Can't find my distro or ubuntu user in Windows terminal WSL2

Tags: windows, terminal

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu v 18.04 distro and Powerlevel10k a theme for Zsh, when I try to start my terminal it sets to something like this  [ ~ ]$ and the common commands are working commands like ls, cd. Also, I can't find my user directory.
[see here a screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNfaj.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

that's a web browser, unless you're running linux inside a browser (which can be pretty laggy), you can't simply do that, if there's more to it, feel free to comment to my answer, or edit the post to include extra info.

Comment: You shouldn't assume its a web browser just because it has tabs. The new Windows Terminal has a tabbed interface.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JonnyWright what do you mean "new terminal"? unless you're talking about windows 11's terminal, mine doesn't have tabs, and i'm also confused now, why would he run linux inside of the windows terminal? doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Becatto Yes I am talking about the Windows 11 terminal, which does support a tabbed interface [(see my screenshot, 21H2)](https://hostr.co/0MPJ5NO0vQYv), and if you use [WSL to install a Linux distro on your Windows machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), then you can use the Windows Terminal app to access the Linux terminal (as shown in my screenshot).

Comment: @JonnyWright then i'm not the right person to answer, since i see terminals as useless.